# Are CA::Render::Encoder::grow crashes due to a bug in iOS 13, or how to fix them?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, crash

(I've found some other QuartzCore crash related questions on StackOverflow but none of them are for the exact context that we have.)

We have an iOS app in the App Store. Recently, we see in Organizer / Crashes for that app a new type of crash that seems bound to iOS 13 devices (21 devices affected in the last few weeks, all with iOS 13.1, .2, or .3). Xcode reports that the crashes occurred in QuartzCore, on CA::Render::Encoder::grow(unsigned long).

Any idea what can it be and how it could be fixed? It doesn't look related to our code. Can it be a recent Apple bug? (We didn't have these crash reports before iOS 13.) Thank you in advance.

Here is an extract from the crash log:

```
OS Version:          iPhone OS 13.3 (17C54)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    2.03.07
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b431aefc __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b423a8b8 pthread_kill + 228 (pthread.c:1458)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001b41caa74 abort + 104 (abort.c:110)
3   QuartzCore                      0x00000001bb0fc3b0 CA::Render::Encoder::grow(unsigned long) + 308 (render-coding.cpp:562)
4   QuartzCore                      0x00000001bb0fcb20 CA::Render::Encoder::encode_data_async(void const*, unsigned long, void (*)(void const*, void*), ... + 180 (render-coding.h:272)
5   QuartzCore                      0x00000001bafb2f78 CA::Render::Image::encode(CA::Render::Encoder*) const + 740 (render-image.cpp:401)
6   QuartzCore                      0x00000001bb0fc438 CA::Render::Encoder::encode_object_uncached(CA::Render::Object const*) + 136 (render-coding.cpp:905)
7   QuartzCore                      0x00000001bafcf9d4 CA::Render::Layer::encode(CA::Render::Encoder*) const + 116 (render-coding.h:388)
8   QuartzCore                      0x00000001bb0fc438 CA::Render::Encoder::encode_object_uncached(CA::Render::Object const*) + 136 (render-coding.cpp:905)
9   QuartzCore                      0x00000001bb100ebc CA::Render::encode_set_object(CA::Render::Encoder*, unsigned long, unsigned int, CA::Render::Obje... + 196 (render-coding.cpp:2151)
10  QuartzCore                      0x00000001bb04094c invocation function for block in CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double) + 1080 (CAContextInternal.mm:1632)
11  QuartzCore                      0x00000001bb0fae1c CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int) block... + 348 (CALayer.mm:2647)
12  QuartzCore                      0x00000001bb0fad98 CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int) block... + 216 (CALayer.mm:2633)
13  QuartzCore                      0x00000001bb0fad98 CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int) block... + 216 (CALayer.mm:2633)
14  QuartzCore                      0x00000001bb0fad98 CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int) block... + 216 (CALayer.mm:2633)
15  QuartzCore                      0x00000001bb0fad98 CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int) block... + 216 (CALayer.mm:2633)
16  QuartzCore                      0x00000001bb0fad98 CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int) block... + 216 (CALayer.mm:2633)
17  QuartzCore                      0x00000001bb0fad98 CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int) block... + 216 (CALayer.mm:2633)
18  QuartzCore                      0x00000001bb0fad98 CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int) block... + 216 (CALayer.mm:2633)
19  QuartzCore                      0x00000001bb0fad98 CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int) block... + 216 (CALayer.mm:2633)
20  QuartzCore                      0x00000001bb0fad98 CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int) block... + 216 (CALayer.mm:2633)
21  QuartzCore                      0x00000001bb0fad98 CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int) block... + 216 (CALayer.mm:2633)
22  QuartzCore                      0x00000001bb0fad98 CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int) block... + 216 (CALayer.mm:2633)
23  QuartzCore                      0x00000001bb0fad98 CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int) block... + 216 (CALayer.mm:2633)
24  QuartzCore                      0x00000001bb0fad98 CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int) block... + 216 (CALayer.mm:2633)
25  QuartzCore                      0x00000001bb0fad98 CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int) block... + 216 (CALayer.mm:2633)
26  QuartzCore                      0x00000001bb03fbc4 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double) + 2868 (CAContextInternal.mm:2288)
27  QuartzCore                      0x00000001bb069fd0 CA::Transaction::commit() + 684 (CATransactionInternal.mm:438)
28  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b8648d60 _afterCACommitHandler + 144 (UIApplication.m:3076)
29  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b44ab524 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 36 (CFRunLoop.c:1758)
30  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b44a61c4 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 420 (CFRunLoop.c:1868)
31  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b44a6774 __CFRunLoopRun + 1292 (CFRunLoop.c:2910)
32  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b44a5f40 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 480 (CFRunLoop.c:3192)
33  GraphicsServices                0x00000001be723534 GSEventRunModal + 108 (GSEvent.c:2246)
34  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b861ea60 UIApplicationMain + 1940 (UIApplication.m:4773)
35  <Our app name>                  0x00000001029ed048 main + 88 (main.m:14)
36  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001b4324e18 start + 4
```

Comment: Note: I also posted the question some time ago [on Apple Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/402129), but I've received no answer yet.